Are investment funds allowed to not invest in companies for ethical reasons?
It is in the news that both Hay and the Edinburgh international book festival have ended its sponsorship with the investment fund Baillie Gifford over their investment in fossil fuels and the Israeli military and settlements in the occupied territories. Baillie Gifford have made a statement (the original of which I have been unable to find) which is quoted as saying:

As spelled out in Baillie Gifford’s statement, it manages other people’s money. It is not allowed to make ethical decisions on their behalf.

This came as a little of a surprise, as there exist things that are considered as Ethical Investment Funds.
What is the law here?  Would it be legal for Baillie Gifford to say refuse to invest in companies that do business with civilian population transferred into the occupied Arab territories contrary to United Nations Security Council Resolution 446?

Funds are generally allowed to invest in Israel (or companies doing business there), or refrain from doing so. The problem is that it is hard to change fund rules in a fundamental way, after people have invested in it. Investing in one country as opposed to another, or going from a passive fund to an actively managed one (e.g. we had a simple index fund but now we're trying hard to get the same returns while avoiding certain undesired companies), are big changes. Depending on the details of how the investment fund is set up, it might well need approval from the national regulator, and from a supermajority of the existing investors. One could also start offering a new fund, and wind up the old one, but that is also a lengthy and difficult process. (Whether that makes business sense to do at all is a separate issue.) As long as the original fund is still running, its management must reflect the basis on which its investors made their investment.
The statement
Baillie Gifford's statement of 24 May 2024 concerning divestment has this to say:

We are a private business managing other people’s money, not our own. In our highly regulated industry, there are some absolute ethical boundaries we follow, as do all UK asset managers. These relate to national laws, regulations, and sanctions. When it comes to subjective ethical situations
relating to sectors (such as fossil fuels) or countries (such as Israel and the Occupied Palestinian Territories), our clients set the parameters and determine what to exclude or divest. We are not able to make exclusions of that nature based on our own ethical judgements, or in response to pressure
from outside groups. Our fiduciary duty to the people or organisations who control the money we manage, is always our overriding priority. Therefore, in asking for divestment the activists are requesting that we breach our duty to our clients.

I think this is the source of the summary in the question.
UN sanctions are not relevant
It is certainly true that Baillie Gifford has to obey UK law, just like everyone else, and so they are barred from breaching UK economic sanctions. As far as the UK is concerned, a Security Council resolution does not have direct effect in domestic law. The UK is obliged by virtue of its UN membership to comply with those resolutions, which it does by making various kinds of orders and regulations, pursuant to enabling primary legislation. It is those regulations that UK companies follow.
Originally, the main avenue was that the United Nations Act 1946 permitted the government to make Orders-in-Council concerning sanctions. This power was cut down as overly broad in HM Treasury v Ahmed [2010] UKSC 2, and the former mechanism for applying EU sanctions no longer applies post-Brexit. So the current enabling legislation, the Sanctions and Anti-Money Laundering Act 2018, is the primary avenue for domestic regulations to be made.
Currently, there is no sanctions regime of this kind applicable to the state of Israel per se. Resolution 446 does not make any direct call on UN member states (other than Israel itself) to do anything, though the UK could still implement sanctions on its own initiative. Various resolutions of the General Assembly have called for sanctions, but these aren't binding as Security Council resolutions are.
There are some provisions of the anti-terrorist and human rights sanctions programmes which are relevant to Israel and the occupied territories, such as asset freezes for certain Israeli settlers - and on the other hand, for people associated with Hamas or Palestinian Islamic Jihad. Accordingly, BG has a legal obligation not to manage investments for those people, but it's not in a position of interpreting UN resolutions on its own.
In the Parliamentary session just ended, the Government put forward a bill (which will now make no more progress) aimed at forbidding local councils and other public bodies from boycotting Israel. Had this been passed, it would not apply to a wholly private company such as Baillie Gifford, who would continue to be able to offer investment products that included or excluded Israel, companies doing business there, etc. But the mere existence of this bill is enough to show that there is otherwise no legal duty for or against investment in Israel.
Funds can have an ethical objective, but can't bait-and-switch
The remainder of the quoted paragraph is about the fund managers' duty to operate a fund in accordance with clients' expectations. There are all sorts of regulations about how funds can be described and advertised, which if printed out will fill many ring binders. But their effect includes things like -

If you offer something called the "No Oil Companies Fund" then you'd better not invest in any oil companies.
If you offer an "S&P 500 Tracker Fund" then you'll have to make it track the S&P 500 as best you can, most likely by acquiring and disposing of stock in those exact companies as their valuations fluctuate.
You are allowed to make changes to an investment scheme. The more fundamental these are, the tougher it will be to get the required approvals from regulators and investors. Turning an index fund into an ESG fund is a major change.
You can wind up a fund, even if it's solvent. There are processes and timescales for this as well, again entailing regulatory approval.
Regulatory action if you break the rules can entail substantial fines, being personally banned from your job, etc. Also, rich angry clients can sue you.

So, while as a fund manager you're perfectly free to offer the "Mega Ethical Only Nice People Fund" alongside the "We Guess Which Number Will Go Up And Then Buy That Fund", it is very hard to turn one into the other. While there's been a lot of attention on greenwashing (e.g. our fund is called the "Save the Planet Fund" but we don't let that affect our decisions), the reverse is also important. People who have invested in any fund have made a decision and are relying on the fund manager to execute their wishes.
With enough business will, and over a period of time, it would be possible for a firm to transition into only offering certain ethical investments; if it's not there yet then it has to respect its clients' instructions.

Funds invest based on their prospectus and investment objectives, not politics. It is not illegal in the United Kingdom to invest in Israel.
Including or excluding investments not according to the prospectus may be considered a breach of contract and fiduciary duty. For investment fund managers, which operate in a highly regulated environment, there may be criminal sanctions for that, but more importantly - it may destroy their investors' trust in them and ruin their business.
Worth remembering that ethics is not a defined concept, and everyone defines their own ethics. The ethical funds you linked to have explicit investment objectives and specific goals that they promise to achieve, and their prospectus will explicitly mention that pursuing these goals may lead to missed opportunities as part of the investors' risk assessment.
In the comments you suggested "they would have to change their prospectus and that would take X time", but it's not just time. Once the fund has taken investors' money it cannot just say "psych, we'll do something else". Investors need to agree to that. There will also be losses associated with such a change which the investors will need to agree to sustain. Investors may not agree with your politics, and may not want to pay the price you want them to pay.
In some cases the Pro-Palestinian pressure groups resort to terrorism (as we all know from what happened in Israel) or criminal blackmail (as we've seen here in the US). They take over property, vandalize, threaten, and cause harm in order to pressure others to abide by their will. In the US for example, some universities decided that the damage that the pro-Palestinian pressure groups may cause them is more than the investment losses of divesting their investments. But that doesn't always end well. In the case of the Sonoma University for example, the university president was fired for bowing to that pressure.
Involving politics in investment decisions is generally bad for business and investors will strongly resist such pressures. It doesn't mean there's no market for funds which would exclude Israel as a whole, or specific companies or industries, but it does mean that it would be very difficult to force such an exclusion on the whole world. It would definitely not be legal.

The question is is it illegal to NOT invest in Israel even if you think you would make money for your customers.

@User65535 it might be a breach of contract or fiduciary duty, depending on the fund's governing documents, yes.

@User65535 worth remembering that ethics is not a defined concept, and everyone defines their own ethics. The ethical funds  you linked to have explicit investment objectives and specific goals that they promise to achieve, and their prospectus will explicitly mention that pursuing these goals may lead to missed opportunities as part of the investors' risk assessment. A fund focusing on rain forests may be investing in Israel, while a fund focusing on advancing Islamic banking might find it against its objectives. Or maybe not.

Then that should be in the answer.  As it is the answer is irrelevant to the question.  It sounds from your comment likely the answer is something like "they would have to change their prospectus and that would take X time".  If so, that would be a perfect answer.

@User65535 incorporated the comments in the answer.
